# Constructor calling a destructor

Tags: c#, constructor, destructor

Is it possible to have a constructor calling a destructor in C#?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since there are no destructors in C#, no.

You are probably thinking of the finalizer which is called by the framework, not user code...so again, the answer is no.

If you're talking about the `Dispose()` method of the `IDisposable` interface, it is possible to call `this.Dispose()` from inside the constructor...but it would be pointless to say the least.

Comment: C# does supports the concept of destructor but the compiler directly the converts the destructors code into an override of Object.Finalize() method.

Comment: For more, refer to this link:- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/chandrahundigam/UnderstandingDestructors11192005021208AM/UnderstandingDestructors.aspx